# call action class multiple times for one inputform in struts

Tags: javascript, struts-1

I have 3 screens where on screen2 has a back button which leads to screen1, next button leads to screen3. Now one more button Add which leads to the same screen2 for different user input. The problem is incase the user clicks 'Add' submit button and then clicks previous then first it should go to the Screen2 wid previous entries and then if clicked back Screen1. How do i achieve this previous screen flow in struts1.1